# C# Calling OpenAI to process audio file doesn't work. With HttpClient or OpenAI NuGet

Tags: c#, openai-api, asp.net-core-6.0

Getting really frustrated with this.  Really wish OpenAI would have some sort of technical help, but whatever.

I am trying to test to see if we can upload a WAV file and have it translate to text.  Their API Documentation indicates they can with the following endpoint:
POST   https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions

Of course there are no code samples using C#, but trying to modify the node one to work with either HttpClient or OpenAI NuGet package, it keeps throwing errors saying bad request.  I even went so far to see if ChatGPT and render the code, which that too fails lol lots of help that is.

For the most part, I've tried this variation:

```
static async Task<string> ConvertAudioToText(string filePath, string apiKey)
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var audioBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);

    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    using var audioContent = new ByteArrayContent(audioBytes);
    audioContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");
    content.Add(audioContent, "model", "whisper-1");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/whisper-1/transcriptions", content);
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseContent;
}
```

Which keeps returning this error message:

> ```
> "error": {
>     "message": "you must provide a model parameter",
>     "type": "invalid_request_error",
>     "param": null,
>     "code": null
> }
> ```

Any help trying to figure this out, would be great.  Any idea why this gives me an error, I provided the model but it keeps asking for it. How do I provide a file and model types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This Should help you.
This is an example of call to get the transcript as SRT file, from an audio (or video) file.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string filePath = "path_to_your_file";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "YOUR_API_KEY");

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { new StringContent("whisper-1"), "model" },
            { new StringContent("srt"), "response_format" },
            { new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray()), "file", filePath }
        };
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", content);
        var transcript = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```